# ipatool failed with an exception: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `toolsPath' for nil:NillClass>

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, ipa

Post upgradation of Xcode to 9.0.1 version, I am experiencing an error "ipatool failed with an exception: # NoMethodError: undefined method `toolsPath' for nil:NilClass" while exporting as iPA in one of my project. Tried exporting other project archives and older version of same project archive, Potentially I was able to export the iPA.

Bitcode is disabled in the project due to constraints in dependency framework. Read some blogs and did not find a convincing answer for this issue. Wish some one can help me understand the issue please?

> Xcode version: 9.0.1
>
> MAC OS Version: 10.13

**ipatool JSON Error response:**

{
            code = 646;
            description = "ipatool failed with an exception: #toolsPath' for nil:NilClass>\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:804:inrawLoadCommands'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:820:in `rpaths'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:259:in`resolveLoadedDylibs'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:1415:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:1414:in`each'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:1414:in `block in initialize'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:1413:in`each'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:1413:in `initialize'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2278:in`new'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2278:in `ProcessIPA'\n    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2929:in`'";
            info =             {
            };
            level = ERROR;
            type = exception;
}

[Screen shot of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7dLz.png)

Answer (score 4):

Resolved Distributing Enterprise mode with `Xcode 9.1`

Even if I removed old framework files, disabled bitcode.. I could not export distribution `ipa` for enterprise or even in development mode with `XCode 9.1`

Finally I just clicked fast next before below red error comes, and O was able to export my ipa.. I think this is `XCode 9.1s` bug or what.

```
ipatool failed with an exception: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `toolsPath' for nil:NillClass>
```

[image]

[image: Select next before error comes..]

[image]

I wrote answer in developer.apple.com 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/90934#thread-message-281096

Answer (score 2):

It can happen for few reasons.

1. Check if the framework dependencies such as Pods are properly imported and ensure they are not built in the release stage.

App>General settings>Linked frameworks and libraries.

[image: Xcode Image]

2. Trying to build the app using a provisioning profile(development) and trying to archive it using a different profile(adhoc or enterprise) can cause this issue.
3. If you have any javascript files/ node modules added to your bundle, then it can cause this error as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue fixed by updating one of my External framework used in my project which was causing the problem

- Removed the old framework files completely from the project
- Commented out the framework dependency code lines to avoid compilation errors
- Archived and Exported the IPA without containing problematic framework to ensure problem is with the Framework

I am unsure on cause of this issue Since I have no control over debugging External framework, but likely an option to try out if you face this issue.

If there are more than one framework and if you are unsure of the problematic framework, try removing one after another.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/273921#273921

Answer (score 1):

I just has this issue. Whilst the workaround suggested by @karan allowed me to create a valid ad-hoc build, it didn't resolve the issue. It turned out I had ended up with a BuildAgent from HockeyApp in my Copy Bundle Resources. I removed this and the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Only Setting **Enable Bitcode** to **No** in **Build Settings** worked for me.