# ipatool failed with an exception, Xcode 11,6

Tags: swift, xcode, archive, distribute, ipatool

**The error: ipatool failed with and exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExitException: ...**

Hello! When I try to distribute my app archive for development and choose rebuild from bitcode, this error appear, but when I uncheck rebuild from bitcode it generates .ipa successfully
I have tried to update Xcode to latest version 11.6, and updating MacOS to 10.15.6, didn't help
I think this problem s after updating to Catalina from Mojave

[Error image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kqkn.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039883/ipatool-failed-with-an-exception-nomethoderror-undefined-method-toolspath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Pod YandexMapKit, version 3.5
Had to change to 3.4

```
pod 'YandexMapKit', '3.4'
```